# AWS Glue job ignores logging settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-cdk

I have a glue job in CDK that looks like this:

```ts
const job = new Job(scope, `${appName}${stageName}GlueJobCloudTrailLogs`, {
    executable: JobExecutable.pythonEtl({
        glueVersion: GlueVersion.V3_0,
        pythonVersion: PythonVersion.THREE,
        script: Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'cloud_trail_logs.py')),
    }),
    role: glueRole,
    jobName: `${appName}${stageName}GlueJobCloudTrailLogs`,
    continuousLogging: {
        enabled: true,
        logGroup,
    },
});
```

When I go to cloudwatch to see the custom log group that was passed, it is empty, and when I see a job run of it, I see this:

[image: image showing continuousLogging disabled]

Then, the trigger I have is:

```ts
new CfnTrigger(scope, `${appName}${stageName}GlueJobCloudTrailLogsTrigger`, {
    type: 'SCHEDULED',
    schedule: 'cron(* * * * ? *)',
    actions: [
        {
            jobName: job.jobName,
            arguments: jobDefaultArguments,
        },

    ],
    startOnCreation: true,
});
```

So, is the setting on the job definition being overwritten by something? Why if I have enabled the logging it still shows as disabled in all job runs?

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion about overwriting is correct.  `CfnTrigger`'s arguments are overwriting the job's.

The `CfnTrigger`'s [arguments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-trigger-action.html) are *"the job arguments used when this trigger fires. For this job run, they replace the default arguments set in the job definition itself."* Arguments are optional in the trigger.

The trigger arguments overwrites the CDK L2 Job construct's logging configuration, which are `defaultArguments`. You can see this in the Job construct's [github source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-glue/lib/job.ts) or in the CDK's CloudFormation template output in your `cdk.out` directory:

```json
// MyStack.template.json
"MyJobE62EB972": {
  ...
  "DefaultArguments": {
    "--job-language": "python",
    "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true",
    "--enable-continuous-log-filter": "true"
  },
  ...
```